# UDP real-time games in Flash/Flex available Open source RTMFP implementation

Tags: networking, actionscript, udp, amf

Are there any examples of using the Flash 10 beta [RTMFP UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Media_Flow_Protocol) based protocol to build real-time Flash games. The RTMFP examples so far seem to focus on P2P networking between flash clients does anyone know of any examples of traditional client/server UDP based communication over RTMFP.

Does anyone know the ability of RTMFP to do [NAT firewall punch-through](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/raknet/manual/natpunchthrough.html) to allow clients to "host" real-time games. Imagine being able to over the web through flash client perform XBox live-like matchmaking and allow a client to host a Flash based realtime "Call of duty"-like game server through a web browser.

It sounds like Adobe's beta [Stratus project](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/#getstarted) provides a "rendevous" service for P2P real-time communication. I believe that is implementing NAT navigation to work around firewalls by coordinating a P2P "rendevous" with a central server.

Also Adobe Labs has another product called [Live Cycle Collaboration Service](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/services/collaboration/):

[Try RTMFP and ClientToClient:](http://blogs.adobe.com/collabmethods/2008/12/try_rtmfp_and_clienttoclient_d.html)

> There are a couple of very interesting
>   problems in using RTMFP. First of all,
>   being UDP-based means that a lot of
>   firewalls just don't allow it. It's
>   pretty common to attempt the
>   connection and fail. Cocomo works
>   around this by attempting a couple of
>   connections at the same time, with a
>   couple of protocols. Whichever
>   succeeds wins the prize of being your
>   session's connection.

LCCS sounds like a "fuller" solution for offering P2P gaming, as well as standard client/server UDP or TCP based gaming. It attempts P2P UDP if that fails it can fall back to client/dedicated server TCP or UDP communication. It seems like this would be something that a game service provider would want to be able to manage themselves (the "cloud" LCCS and Stratus services don't give enough control on the "server-side" for game servers), is there any work on an open source equivalent to these "rendevous" NAT punchthrough and TCP fallback services?

Anyone know of any open source projects that support RTMFP (or any other Flash 10 beta UDP protocol)? Are there any real-time game example of using RTMFP?

Comment: Good question! Fiftheen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenRTMFP with Cumulus
https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus
;)

Comment: damnit, I just read that we still need the FMS to use Cyrrus. So that's why you made Cumulus, nice I'll check it out.

Comment: No, we dont need FMS to run Cirrus.

Answer (score 3):

I made a game over the summer that uses Stratus.  It's not open source, mostly because I've been too lazy to post the code anywhere  The game is multiplayer-tower-defense.com.
Another utility I made using Stratus is BelugaFile, which is open source.  [BelugaFile](http://www.belugafile.com) is a p2p file transfer utility using AIR.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a realtime multiplayer tictactoe built with Adobe Stratus.

http://timepurge.com/tictactoe/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rtmpd.com/wiki/rtmfp - hire used to be some reverse engineering doc. You can still grab this page from Google's cache. I wonder why the page was removed.

I think there isn't available any Open Source implementation (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Haxball it's a p2p game and uses rtmfp.

It started in august 2010, and it's getting pretty popular.

> I've been working on HaxBall since
>   August 2010. The project started quite
>   aimless as merely an experiment with
>   the new P2P capabilites of the Flash
>   Player. It slowly turned into what the
>   game is today.

It's running on [Google AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/).

http://haxball.appspot.com/

Comment: Doug did you use cirrus or fms to manage the users for haxBall?